# Convergence of a mollifier function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convolution, pointwise-convergence, measurable-sets

Let $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ continuous function such as $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$.
Let $\rho_{n}$ unit mollifier. Let, for $n\geq 1$,
$A_{n}:=\gamma \star \rho_{n}([0,1])$ and $A=\gamma ([0,1])$.

Is it true that
$$\lim_{n }\int \chi_{A_{n}}(x)dx=\int \chi_{A}(x)dx.$$
$\chi$ is the indicator function.

I would like to use the TCD but I can't prove the pointwise convergence.